# How to write this SQL Server query: Add values in unique rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like below. The relation between table are:

Each truck may have multiple drivers. Table List connects the each row in table Truck with rows in table Driver. Now I want to get the count of unique Trucks under certain condition, and the total size of the unique Trucks under that condition.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT t.Year AS [Year]
        , t.Month AS [Month]
        , t.Day AS [Day]

        -- Count will not count NULL
        , COUNT( DISTINCT (CASE WHEN (t.Sent = 1 AND r.Internal=1) THEN L.TruckId
                ELSE NULL
            END) ) AS [Count]

        , SUM(CASE WHEN (t.Sent = 1 AND r.Internal = 1) THEN t.Size
            END) AS [Size]

FROM Truck t
INNER JOIN List L ON t.Id = L.TruckId
        INNER JOIN Driver r ON L.DriverId = r.Id
GROUP BY t.Year, t.Month, t.Day
```

- the COUNT is correct, but the SUM is not.

My question is how to get this SUM? **And I do not want to write 2 queries and join them.**

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "sum is not"?, what value are you expecting?, first i recommend you use the "else" clause like this:  SUM(CASE WHEN (t.Sent = 1 AND r.Internal = 1) THEN t.Size ELSE 0
            END) AS [Size]

Answer (score 2):

You can try query like below:

```
; with cte as (
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
      t.Year AS [Year]
    , t.Month AS [Month]
    , t.Day AS [Day]
    , L.TruckId,
    , t.Size
FROM Truck t
INNER JOIN List L ON t.Id = L.TruckId
INNER JOIN Driver r ON L.DriverId = r.Id
WHERE t.Sent = 1 AND r.Internal=1
)
select 
      Year
    , Month
    , Day
    , count(TruckId) AS [Count]
    , sum(Size) AS [Size]
from cte 
group by Year, Month, Day
```

Comment: This is not functionally equivalent! The query in the question will return trucks regardless of:  `t.Sent = 1 AND r.Internal=1`